# How to make this image slider responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The images are cut off at the bottom if the screen gets smaller.

**I created a jsfiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/zjbrm6e4/

Link to the project:

http://printnil.com/products/sammelmappe?variant=1000940579

This works but does not look the best:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 304px) { .royalSlider {min-height: 207px;} }
@media only screen and (min-width: 344px) { .royalSlider {min-height: 235px;} }
@media only screen and (min-width: 384px) { .royalSlider {min-height: 262px;} }
@media only screen and (min-width: 424px) { .royalSlider {min-height: 289px;} }
@media only screen and (min-width: 464px) { .royalSlider {min-height: 316px;} }
@media only screen and (min-width: 504px) { .royalSlider {min-height: 344px;} }
@media only screen and (min-width: 544px) { .royalSlider {min-height: 371px;} }
@media only screen and (min-width: 584px) { .royalSlider {min-height: 398px;} }
@media only screen and (min-width: 624px) { .royalSlider {min-height: 425px;} }
@media only screen and (min-width: 664px) { .royalSlider {min-height: 453px;} }
@media only screen and (min-width: 704px) { .royalSlider {min-height: 480px;} }
@media only screen and (min-width: 744px) { .royalSlider {min-height: 507px;} }
@media only screen and (min-width: 784px) { .royalSlider {min-height: 535px;} }
@media only screen and (min-width: 824px) { .royalSlider {min-height: 562px;} }
@media only screen and (min-width: 864px) { .royalSlider {min-height: 589px;} }
@media only screen and (min-width: 904px) { .royalSlider {min-height: 616px;} }
@media only screen and (min-width: 944px) { .royalSlider {min-height: 644px;} }
@media only screen and (min-width: 984px) { .royalSlider {min-height: 671px;} } 
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) { .royalSlider {min-height: 750px;} }
```

Comment: Actually, it's responsive on chrome 38 for mac . . .

Answer (score 0):

i don't have MUCH knowledge in css but i think i found the issue.

On `resize`, your slider is altering the height of `rsOverflow` also. so, when the screen size is very small its changing the height of `rsOverflow` to less than the `image's` height

You have three way to solve this

1. You can write a media query only for that
2. Edit the plugin script and change the logic which updates the height
3. Write a function which alters the height on load and on resize.

Sample code for the 3rd example is

```
var updateHeight = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        var $img = $('.rsSlide img');
        $img.closest('.rsOverflow').css('height',$img.height()+"px");
    },100); // setTimeout is required since it should run after the plugin has updated the height. 
}
$(window).resize(updateHeight).load(updateHeight);
```